# Using jQuery to slideToggle a group of Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, slidetoggle

I'm fairly new to javaScript and jQuery, so hopefully this will be a quick fix.  I need to display a table containing data that can be grouped into several categories, and I'd like to implement a slideToggle that hides/reveals all of the observations in each given category.

The code below should (ideally) display a table with 4 columns and 9 rows, with every group of 3 rows preceded by a green "Section i" row.  I would like each Section header to work as a slideToggle that expands or collapses all of the rows beneath it.  Right now, nothing is collapsing.  Any thoughts?

```
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    td{padding:5px;}
  </style>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript"> 
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".flip").click(function(){
          $(this).next(".section").slideToggle();
      });
  });
  </script>

</head>

<body>
    <p>
        <table id="main_table">
        <thead>
            <tr class="firstline">
                <th>Column1</th>
                <th>Column2</th>
                <th>Column3</th>
                <th>Column4</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr style="background-color:green; color:white"> 
                <td  colspan="4" class="flip"> Section 1 </td> 
            </tr>
            <div class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 111</td>
                <td>item 112</td>
                <td>item 113</td>
                <td>item 114</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 121</td>
                <td>item 122</td>
                <td>item 123</td>
                <td>item 124</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 131</td>
                <td>item 132</td>
                <td>item 133</td>
                <td>item 134</td>
            </tr>
            </div>
            <tr style="background-color:green; color:white"> 
                <td  colspan="4" class="flip"> Section 2 </td> 
            </tr>
            <div class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 211</td>
                <td>item 212</td>
                <td>item 213</td>
                <td>item 214</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 221</td>
                <td>item 222</td>
                <td>item 223</td>
                <td>item 224</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 231</td>
                <td>item 232</td>
                <td>item 233</td>
                <td>item 234</td>
            </tr>
            </div>
            <tr style="background-color:green; color:white"> 
                <td  colspan="4" class="flip"> Section 3 </td> 
            </tr>
            <div class="section">
            <tr>
                <td>item 311</td>
                <td>item 312</td>
                <td>item 313</td>
                <td>item 314</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 321</td>
                <td>item 322</td>
                <td>item 323</td>
                <td>item 324</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>item 331</td>
                <td>item 332</td>
                <td>item 333</td>
                <td>item 334</td>
            </tr>
            </div>
        </tbody>
        </table>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: First: You cannot use `div` between `table` and `td`. Second: There is no element *next()* to the `td.flip` (it has no siblings).

Comment: I had real issues trying to do something similar with jQuery and tables, it seems tables don't really play ball that well so I ditched the table and used divs instead works much better :-)

Comment: can you please post the final working code here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't mix `<div>`s into a `<table>` like that, use additional `<tbody>` elements instead. In your callback, `this` is the `<td>` element which has no siblings so `.next` does nothing useful; you want to go back up until you get to something that is at the same depth as the `.section` you're interested in and then call `.next` from there.

Your HTML should look more like this:

```
<table id="main_table">
    <thead>
        <tr class="firstline">
            <th>Column1</th>
            <th>Column2</th>
            <th>Column3</th>
            <th>Column4</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr style="background-color:green; color:white">
            <td  colspan="4" class="flip"> Section 1 </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tbody class="section">
        <tr>
            <td>item 111</td>
            <td>item 112</td>
            <td>item 113</td>
            <td>item 114</td>
        </tr>
        <!-- ... -->
```

And your click handler like this:

```
$('.flip').click(function() {
    $(this)
        .closest('tbody')
        .next('.section')
        .toggle('fast');
});
```

The [`.closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) call goes back up your ancestors until it finds a `<tbody>` and then you call `.next` on that.

Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/Udxyb/4/

Comment: Note that the original question asks for slideToggle, which apparently doesn't work with this method. Changing `toggle` to `slideToggle` breaks the animation. http://jsfiddle.net/m83Pc/

Comment: @supertrue: This was quite awhile ago so I'm not sure where the `slideToggle` to `toggle` switch came from. I suspect that the animation problem is a side effect of the usual display and nesting issues inside `<table>`. I'll poke around a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: @supertrue: If you switch to `slideToggle(10000)` and watch the `.section` in a good DOM inspector, you'll see that the animation just adjusts the `height`. You'll also notice that `<tbody>` ignores `height` completely (sorry, I don't have a definitive reference for this) unless you change its `display` (http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/m83Pc/1/) but that causes other strangeness.