# Setting a <tr> as a block shows the contents of the <td>'s in the same column

Tags: jquery, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [slideToggle in table row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row)

I have a table and I'm using jquery's `slideToggle()` to show and hide some rows.

Slidetoggle doesn't works ok (it doesn't animate) if you don't show the element `<tr>` to toggle as a block (`display:block`).

The problem: if I set the `<tr>` as a block, it shows the content of `<td>`'s in the same column (the first).

Here you have:

http://jsfiddle.net/7LH3p/6/

Any idea?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126704/slidetoggle-in-table-row...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To animate TR's I recommend you to enclose the TD contents in divs, then animate the divs, see my working [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/F6Vw2/1/).

Comment: yes, it works smoother with divs.

Comment: Yes it's smoother, it's how I use it on my projects because animating the TD's or TR's directly causes bad results from my experience.

Comment: anyway what I was looking for is to slide the content of a group of trs. I found something about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5111826/using-jquery-to-slidetoggle-a-group-of-table-rows . My question: is there any way to use `slideToggle()` instead of `toggle()` in that case?

Answer (score 1):

I think it may be because you are making just ONE tr have a style of block.  When I set them all to be block looks like everything lines up alright:

http://jsfiddle.net/yuadX/